# What are some good resources to help me implement Kerberos A&A support in PHP?

Tags: php, kerberos

I am working on a website and I have to implement Kerberos for authentication and authorization.  I already know how kerberos works internally but I am not sure how to implement support for it in PHP. I am using a version 5 for kerberos and have an apache server. I have [only found one article](http://php.net/manual/en/book.kadm5.php), but it just gives basic information. Please suggest additional articles and resources on implementing Kerberos authentication and authorization in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mod_auth_kerb`](http://modauthkerb.sourceforge.net/index.html) for your purpose.