# Kerberos implementation in PHP?

Tags: php, kerberos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some good resources to help me implement Kerberos A&A support in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098763/what-are-some-good-resources-to-help-me-implement-kerberos-aa-support-in-php)

I am working on a website and I have to implement Kerberos for authentication and authorization. I already know how kerberos works internally but I am not sure how to implement support for it in PHP. I am using a version 5 for kerberos and have an apache server. I have only found one article, but it just gives basic information. Please suggest additional articles and resources on implementing Kerberos authentication and authorization in PHP.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.kadm5.php

Comment: I have already seen that link. It has a very basic detail.

Comment: I posted that question a few days ago but found no response.